# Iterate through JSON array with a closure

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

In Groovy (specifically in Jenkins), I have a JSON Array read in from a file using the readJSON method.

Looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "bob",
    "age": "36"
  },
  {
    "name": "wizard",
    "age": "420"
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through each array index with a closure like withEachIndex. When I run something like:

```
array.withEachIndex { it, i ->
  println it.name
  println it.age
  println "Index: ${i}"
}
```

Jenkins chokes:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: net.sf.json.JSONArray.withEachIndex() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@f048bab]
```

I've tried turning the array into a Java array (by calling .toArray() on it) and turning it into a collection (by calling .toCollection() on it) but those also didn't have closure methods.

How can I convert this object to an array that I can use a closure method on in Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for this `eachWithIndex`:

```
def arr = [
  [
    "name": "bob",
    "age": "36"
  ],
  [
    "name": "wizard",
    "age": "420"
  ]
]
arr.eachWithIndex { n, i -> println( "${i}: ${n.name} ${n.age}") }
```

Comment: The issue was that I had used `readJSON` to read in the raw JSON file, which returned a JSON Array. If you set the `returnPojo: true` option, it returns the object as an ArrayList instead of a Java JSON Array, which is missing a bunch of Groovy manipulation methods. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: An `ArrayList` would have the Groovy manipulation methods on it as it's attached to any `List` class.  Now I could see how a JSONArray, which comes from json-lib, might not.  You could try using `readJSON( file: myFile,  returnPojo: true ) as List` which might overcome the issues.  Could it be that you tried it with `withEachIndex` instead of `eachWithIndex` that caused the confusion?